# using unicode in Google translate url from python script

Tags: python, api, unicode, google-translate

I'm trying to use my script to automatically using google translate apis from russian to english. Here is the code.

```
mytext = {some text in russian}
url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q='+ mytext +'&langpair=ru%7Cen'
request = urllib2.Request(url, None, {'Referer': 'http://www.mysite.org'})
```

Now I've tried using various encodings for mytext, including unicode, utf-8, windows-1251 but it never works. Either the urllib.request complains of non-ascii characters or google returns an error code. Any idea if I need any codec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/language/translate?v=1.0&q=' \
    + urllib2.quote(mytext) + '&langpair=ru%7Cen'
```

to quote your text